# How can I check the user ID of someone who uses a command with my bot

Tags: python, command, discord.py

When someone uses a command with my discord bot (discord.py), I want to check their user ID, if it is equal to mine, then it says hello back and says my rank. But it wont work, any ideas?

Heres my current code:

```
class rank(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, client):
        self.client = client

    @commands.command(aliases=["perms"])
    async def rank(self, ctx, member):
        if client.author.id == xxxx:
            await ctx.send(f"Your rank is Bot Owner..\nHello Chaseyy")
            return
        elif client.author.id == xx:
            await ctx.send("Your rank is Bot Admin\nHello Name")
            return
        else:
            await ctx.send("You are a Bot User")
        return
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do the following to retrieve the user id of an message:

```
ctx.author.id
```

The `ctx` param contains all the information about the message sent. Using: `ctx.author` we retrieve the user. Using `ctx.author.id` we retrieve the id of that user.